# "Must declare the scalar variable @Idx" when using a Dapper query on SQL server via OleDb

Tags: ms-access, oledb, dapper, sql-server-express

This code works when the connection is made to an accdb database:

```
Dim customer = connection.Query(Of Klantgegevens)("Select Actief,Onderhoudscontract From Klantgegevens Where Klantnummer=@Idx", New With {.Idx = customerId}).SingleOrDefault
```

But the code below gives the error about the Idx parameter when the connection is made to a SQL server database that has a table with the same structure:

```
Dim customer = connection.Query(Of Klantgegevens)("Select Actief,Onderhoudscontract From [dbo.Klantgegevens] Where Klantnummer=@Idx", New With {.Idx = customerId}).SingleOrDefault
```

What is going wrong here? I had hoped that by using Dapper I would be able to write database agnostic code. But it seems that is not the case!

Comment: is that an odbc or ado.net connection?

Comment: as @krishKM asks: what **exactly** is `connection`? is it a `SqlConnection`? or something else? the reason this matters is that ODBC/ADODB have different parameter usage to SqlClient, so: it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an ODBC/OLEDB connection, then my first suggestion would be: move to `SqlClient` (`SqlConnection`). Everything should work fine with `SqlConnection`.

If you can't do that for some reason - i.e. you're stuck with a provider that doesn't have good support for named parameters - then you might need to tell dapper to use pseudo-positional parameters. Instead of `@Idx`, use `?Idx?`. Dapper interprets this as an instruction to replace `?Idx?` with the *positional* placeholder (simply: `?`), using the value from the member `Idx`.

This is also a good fix for talking to accdb, which has *very* atypical parameter usage for an ADO.NET provider: it allows named parameter tokens, but all the tokens all replaced with `?`, and given values *from the positions of the added parameters* (not via their names).

Comment: Thanks. I chose the solution that keeps the OleDbConnection. The working connectionstring=`"Select Actief,Onderhoudscontract From Klantgegevens Where Klantnummer=?Idx?"`

Comment: @Dabblernl I'm curious... *why?* `SqlConnection` will work *far better* in most ways...

Comment: I do not like to be forced to initialize either a OleDbConnection or a SqlConnection depending on the connection string. Now the code works irrespective of the connection string.

Comment: @Dabblernl you can abstract over that using `DbProviderFactory`, but: as seen above: they require different syntax, so maybe you're better off with your current code